# JSON array get length

Tags: java, json

I can't get the array length of the JSON array. when I using length(); method it is not working, it show as red underline in Netbeans

this is the source code

```
 try {

        JSONObject myjson = JSONObject.fromObject(practiceInfoByUsername);

        //JSONArray nameArray = myjson.names();
        final JSONArray jar = myjson.getJSONArray("_types");
        for(int i=0; i<jar.length(); i++)
        {
            String p = jar.getString(i);
            Log.i("p",p);


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Does it compile? May be issue with netbean's highlighting.

Answer (score 50):

Note: if you're using(importing) `org.json.simple.JSONArray`, you have to use `JSONArray.size()` to get the data you want. But use `JSONArray.length()` if you're using `org.json.JSONArray`.

Answer (score 7):

have you tried size() ?
Something like :

```
jar.size();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I came here and looking how to get the number of elements inside a `JSONArray`. From your question i used `length()` like that:

```
JSONArray jar = myjson.getJSONArray("_types");
System.out.println(jar.length());
```

and it worked as expected. On the other hand `jar.size();`(as proposed in the other answer) is not working for me.

So for future users searching (like me) how to get the size of a `JSONArray`, `length()` works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The below snippet works fine for me(I used the size())

```
String itemId;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject)itemList.get(i);
            itemId=(String) itemObj.get("ItemId");
            System.out.println(itemId);
            }
```

If it is wrong to use use size() kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

Check you have the line:

```
 import org.json.JSONArray;
```

at the top of your source code

Answer (score 0):

The JSONArray.length() returns the number of elements in the JSONObject contained in the Array. Not the size of the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

At my Version the function to get the lenght or size was `Count()`

You're Welcome, hope it help someone.