# JSON index 2 out of range exception

Tags: java, json

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "value": {
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "store_categories_id": "10",
                "description": "Chicken Briyani",
                "unit_price": "120",
                "pro_descripaation": "",
                "pro_image": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "store_categories_id": "10",
                "description": "Vegetable Thali",
                "unit_price": "100",
                "pro_descripaation": "",
                "pro_image": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

ERROR:org.json.JSONException: Index 2 out of range [0..2)

```
try{
    JSONArray product_array = value_array.getJSONArray("products");
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        if (status.equals("true")) {
            // progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (status.equals("true")) {

            // progressDialog.dismiss();
            JSONObject jsonobject = product_array.getJSONObject(i);

            ProductList productList = new ProductList();

            productList.setDescription(jsonobject.getString(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION));

            productList.setId(jsonobject.getString(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_ID));
            Log.v("ganesh","keyboard");
            productListArray.add(productList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException exception) {
    // progressDialog.dismiss();
    Log.e("--JSON EXCEPTION--", exception.toString());
}
```

Can any one help me sort out this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things in your code that don't seem right, but because I don't have the whole context, two things in particular are strange:

1. Your for loop is from 0 until `response.length()`, which is probably more than you have objects in your `product_array`. So you get out of range exception with `product_array.getJSONObject(i);` You might want to use `product_array.size()` or `product_array.length()`, [depending on your import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26818069/4185106).
2. Your `if..else if` is incorrect. You check twice for `status.equals("true")` which means the code never comes to the second `if`.

Answer (score 0):

private void callAPI_togetproducts() {`enter code here
//        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(StoreMenuActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Requesting...", true);`enter code here
//        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);`enter code here`
        OnRequestCompletedListener listener = new OnRequestCompletedListener() {`enter code here`
            @Override`enter code here`
            public void onRequestCompleted(String response) {
                Log.v("--OUTPUT STORE MENU--", response.toString());
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                //progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                    final String status = obj.getString("status");
                    final String value = obj.getString("value");
                    JSONObject value_array = obj.getJSONObject("value");

```
                JSONArray product_array = value_array.getJSONArray("products");

               //  final int product_array = response.length();
                //final int response = products.length();

                for ( int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {


                    if (status.equals("false")) {
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (status.equals("true")) {
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();

                        JSONObject jsonobject = product_array.getJSONObject(i);
                        ProductList productList = new ProductList();
                        productList.setDescription(jsonobject.getString(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION));
                       productList.setId(jsonobject.getString(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT_ID));
                        productListArray.add(productList);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException exception) {
                // progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("--JSON EXCEPTION--", exception.toString());
            }
        }
    };
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    // token
    String api_token = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_APITOKEN);

    ServiceCalls.callAPI_togetproducts(this, Request.Method.POST,Constants.GET_PRODUCTS, listener, api_token,id);
}
```

Comment: I think you got the context

Comment: how to use that product.length() in the above context?