# How to count number of elements from JSON using java

Tags: java, rest

I am pretty new to java and rest. I was trying to count elements from the `item` object using rest. If you check below Json then you will find 6 elements associated with the item object.

```
{
  "response": {
    "status": "active",

    "timestamp": "2019-01-02 20:07:42"
  },

  "group": [
    {

      "best_option": "Offer",
      "item": {
        "F": [
          {
            "code": "228"
          }
        ],
        "E": [
          {
            "code": "228"
          }
        ]
      },
      "review": {
        "F": [
          {
            "code": "110"
          },
          {
            "code": "212"
          }
        ],
        "E": [
          {
            "code": "110"
          },
          {
            "code": "212"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "best_option": "Offer",
      "item": {
        "D": [
          {
            "code": "228"
          }
        ],
        "C": [
          {
            "code": "228"
          }
        ]
      },
      "review": {
        "D": [
          {
            "code": "110"
          },
          {
            "code": "212"
          }
        ],
        "C": [
          {
            "code": "110"
          },
          {
            "code": "212"
          },
          {
            "code": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "best_option": "Offer",
      "item": {
        "A": [
          {
            "code": "228"
          }
        ]
      },
      "review": {
        "A": [
          {
            "code": "110"
          },
          {
            "code": "212"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {

      "best_option": "Offer",
      "item": {
        "B": [
          {
            "code": "228"
          },
          {
            "code": "662"
          }
        ]
      },
      "review": {
        "B": [
          {
            "code": "110"

          },
          {
            "code": "662"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried `jsonResponse.getBody().jsonPath().get()` to count element from item object. I want to count number of elements present in the item object for e.g: A, B, C,D,E F . Can someone please help me to sort out my issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON array get length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268099/json-array-get-length)

Comment: I don't think so this is duplicate. I already check above solution and i am not trying to check json array . please read my question clearly

Comment: "still  facing issue" is not a clear statement of your problem. Please explain what issue you are facing exactly.

Comment: I am not able to count element from item object. i want to count number of elements present in the item object for e.g: A, B, C,D,E F

Comment: Iterate the JSON items and save the `item.*.code` in a `Set` so that you can get the distinct value easily. This is quite simple to do but base on the JSON library you are using (if you are using one...) the solution may vary so I can't help you more

Comment: @AxelH: which json library you are using ?

Comment: Well the question is yours to answer... I don't really have a preference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over `"group"` object, get `"item"` as `JsonObject` and get the `size`.

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)new JsonParser().parse(input);
    JsonArray groupObject = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("group");

    int countItem=0;
    for(int i=0;i<groupObject.size();i++) {
        JsonObject items = ((JsonObject)groupObject.get(i)).getAsJsonObject("item");
        countItem+=items.size();
    }
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @IcedDante Google's "Gson" https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1